# Visual Studio 2010 auto hide toolbox tab

Tags: visual-studio-2010, animation, toolbox

In VS 2010 when you drag one control to your page (left mouse button is still clicked and cursor is on the page area) so the toolbox tab (from your left side - and auto hide) is still there and it seems auto hide not work.

But in VS 2008 everything was ok!

What is the problem about that / I am looking for this answer because when you drag something on your page you can not see the right element for dropping that control !!!

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you drag a control from the toolbox to somewhere within the design canvas but *not* onto your form, the toolbox will remain visible despite auto-hide being enabled. Notice the mouse cursor will have the "NO" symbol (circle with a line through it) while over the canvas area. Once you successfully place the control onto the form somewhere, the toolbox will auto-hide.

Comment: so this reaction sucks / we need to see our form for finding the right place 4 drap / but in this reaction we can't / i do not think repairing vs solve this pro / are there other people that have the same issue? (in visual studio 2008 that was ok)

Comment: Some suggestions: 1. Make the floating toolbox panel narrower, in the case that your form cannot be seen when the toolbox is over it. 2. As Majd suggested, select the container you want to place the control in, and double-click the control from the toolbox. 3. Unpin the toolbox and move the panel to the right side of VS. Depending on your layout, this will allow small forms to be visible while the toolbox is shown.

Answer (score 0):

Autohide is working well for me, however, if you are having a problem you can try the following:

- try pinning and then unpinning the toolbox
- if you want to drop the control in a certain area .. select that area (one left click on the element where you wanna add the control) and then double click on the control you want to add and it will be added to where you want it and then you can place it
- if that didn't work .. (and it should) .. try repairing MS VS2010

Comment: By "repairing" Visual Studio, do you mean uninstall and reinstall? Or is there some other repair technique?

Comment: For me, i pin the tool box to the view and that's it .. when i don't need it i simply unpin it so i have a wider view .. i would suggest that! cuz the autohide gets annoying sometimes